# how to justify content to the end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have one background image in a container class.  I divided as col -6. first col-6 is empty.However, I want to put content on the right side of the col-6. I tried to do it by adding justify-content-end class but it did not work. It appears as below. [what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bFMr.jpg). However I want to display it like below [what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAvTM.jpg)

```
<div class="main-contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 justify-content-end">
                    <div class="main-about-content">
                        <h3>Hayal Ettiğiniz Mobilya ile </h3><br>
                            <span>
                                Bahçenizi Tamamlayalım.
                            </span>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                            laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
                            architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                        <a href="iletisim.html">Detaylı Bilgi</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

.main-contact {
background-image: url(../img/Asset6.png);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }


.main-about-content {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255, 0.3);
       color: white;
       padding: 65px 40px;
       text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)

```css
.main-contact {
  background-image: url(https://images.theconversation.com/files/393210/original/file-20210401-13-z6rl6z.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=9%2C0%2C2994%2C1999&q=45&auto=format&w=496&fit=clip);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main-about-content {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
  padding: 65px 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="main-contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="offset-sm-6 col-sm-6 justify-content-end">
      <div class="main-about-content">
        <h3>Hayal Ettiğiniz Mobilya ile </h3><br>
        <span>
          Bahçenizi Tamamlayalım.
        </span>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        <a href="iletisim.html">Detaylı Bilgi</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used `offset-sm-6 col-sm-6` to make the result visible in the snippet, but feel free to use `offset-lg-6 col-lg-6` for your project if you want it only on large screens.

Comment: It worked  thanks a lot. I have one problem I want to float right each tag when I do that, the background does not cover all the content. How can I fix it?

Comment: @pattes feel free to ask another question for a different problem :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try `align-self-end` class, as described in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

you can 2 ways for justify-content to the end

first Type use CSS `text-align:right;` and
Second Type use `display:flex; justify-content:end;`

```
div{display:flex; justify-content:end;}

<div> hello </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a row

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-12">
        -------
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```